# I am getting a No route matches error while trying to reroute to a new page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby on rails , I was making a basic app that lets you display posts, after which we can access a new page where a user can enter new posts.

But the problem now is , upon clicking the submit button I get this error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"} missing required keys: [:id]

This is the content inside my post controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all       
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @post =Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    if  @post.save
      redirect_to post_path,:notice=>"success"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:Title, :Content)
  end
end
```

after this i tried to reload to check if there was an update at all , but all i got was empty entries

rake route command displays

```
nevin@NevinSunny:~/Workspace/Rails/Test1/blog$ rake routes


   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
    posts GET    /posts(.:format)          posts#index
          POST   /posts(.:format)          posts#create
 new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
     post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
          PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
```

Comment: Screenshots don't add anything to understanding problems like this one, you'd only include screenshots if your problem was a visual issue that couldn't be explained in words and code.

Comment: I've edited your post now to remove those screenshots, and improve the formatting of the bits of text that are crucial to people being able to understand the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `create` action:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  if  @post.save
    redirect_to @post, :notice => "success"
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

### Edit:

In response to your comment:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  if  @post.save
    redirect_to posts_path, :notice=>"success"
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

Comment: hey , firstly thanks for the reply , but this one is redirecting to the newly created post . I want it to redirect to the initial page  ../posts (the first image) the page which displays all available posts.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple, When you say:

```
redirect_to post_path
```

you need to pass ID, as the error indicates:

```
redirect_to post_path(@post)
```

alternatively follow convention:

```
redirect_to @post
```

Comment: hey , firstly thanks for the reply , but this one is redirecting to the newly created post . I want it to redirect to the initial page  ../posts (the first image) the page which displays all available posts.

Comment: Again Nevin with the followup question (or addition to your original question this time) without upvoting an answer you found useful. I will point you once again to [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Quick tip: when you `rake routes` you will see the list or possible URIs. As you read through them, you will see which action they point to and what parameters they require. Index action will use `post` prefix (first column) you need to add `_url` or `_path` depending if you want full url or just relative link. show action requires ID since you're looking for a specific post therefore after assembling path you need to pass id: `post_path(IDgoeshere)` you can also pass whole object and let Rails match the ID: `post_path(@post)`